# How to map oneToMany using ModelMapper

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

I am using `springBoot`, I want to map `OneToMany` relationship from parent to child. Directly using `entity` with `eager` fetching I get recursive records, therefore, trying using `ModelMapper` for `DTO` mapping to `Entity` but I am not able to figure out how to do it. Please assume `getters` and `setters`.

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private int parentId;

    private String a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> child;
```

**Child.java**

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private int childId;

    private String c;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b")
    private Parent parent;
```

I have working repository and servicelayer with `findAll` method.

**ParentDto.java**

```
public class ParentDto {

    private String a;

    private Set<Child> child;
```

**ParentController.java**

```
@RestController
public class ParentController {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ParentService parentService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/parents" )
    public List<ParentDto> getParents() {
        List<Parent> parents =  parentService.getAll();
        return parents.stream()
                .map(x-> modelMapper.map(x, ParentDto.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Error:** While trying to fetch `http://localhost:8080/parents`

```
.
.
ModelMapper mapping errors: 1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.CollectionConverter@51381583 failed to convert java.util.Set to java.util.Set. 1 error
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.CollectionConverter@51381583 failed to convert java.util.Set to java.util.Set.

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:380)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:80)
.
.
```

Comment: Whats the issue with recursive set of records?

Comment: 1) Directly passing domain/entity to frontend is not recommended. 2) By recursive I mean infinite loop of `parent->child->parent->child.....` and JVM crashes. That's obviously a problem. I might get around that problem by using `eager` at parent and `lazy` at child though haven't tried, for the same I switched to `DTO`

Comment: And that is why `EAGER` is **not** the recommended fetch type... You can also always write your own custom mapper for domain model to DTO

Comment: And without the configuration of  your `ModelMapper` we cant help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  Yes :( and I am not able to configure it. I tried to use `LOOSE` strategy but that didn't help and I don't see any examples of configuring nested objects.

Comment: You don't need a DTO.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for this but really I am looking to use `DTO` for future uses also. I might get around for this example but have other cases to handle.

Comment: You manually need to break the recursion by setting parent inside child of main parent object as null, before mapping entity to dto.

Comment: https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/89 You really need to simply google the exception

Comment: There are better strategies for controlling the JSON representation of your entities than duplicating your entity model as DTO classes and writing tedious mapping code. Jackson mix-in classes and Spring Data projections for example.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with “N + 1” and  “Infinite Recursion” issue ，May be add Conver method to mapper；
Mapping Children with ModelMapper
https://amydegregorio.com/2018/10/03/mapping-children-with-modelmapper/

Comment: This blog use MapStruct to mapping one to many relation；“Automating Code with MapStruct：https://medium.com/@swathisprasad/automating-code-with-mapstruct-44b8c324a23e”

Answer (score 0):

I propose "Preferred nested properties".
http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration

Comment: @AttilaT My answer contains more than just a link

Comment: Prefixing a link with a sentence that contains only five words, three out of which are direct quote from the page linked is essentially a link-only answer.

Comment: @AttilaT I indicated a specific place to use the link. That is why I quoted him exactly.

Answer (score -1):

> You need to use @JsonIgnore annotation on the parent mapping defined
>   in your child entity.

Refer this documentation for more info - 
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html